# Android: UrMatcher

Tags: java, android

```
public class PatanjliProvider extends ContentProvider {
     static final String PROVIDER_NAME = 
     "com.example.hplapi.myuriprovider.PatanjliProvider";
      static final String URL = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/students";
      static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL);

      static final String _ID = "_id";
      static final String NAME = "name";
      static final String GRADE = "grade";

      static final int STUDENTS = 1;
      //whole data retrieve

      static final int STUDENT_ID = 2;
      static final int STUDENTNAME = 3;
      static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
      //for  matching
      static{
          uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
          //check directly
          uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students", STUDENTS);
          //check with whole data
          uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students/#", STUDENT_ID);
          //check with particular id
          uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students/", STUDENTNAME);
          //I am trying this.Is this work
      }
}
```

**Friends I am learning android. I am new for android.Here in this code I 
    want to make uriMatcher on the bases of Name  and i used this statement in 
    the code *uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "students/", STUDENTNAME)*. Is 
    this  possible to make urimatcher on the bases of Name.If yes then correct 
    this  code because this code is not working on the basis of Name. If not 
    describe 
    why**